# How to sorting the data Table according to date dd-mm-yyyy format in html?

Tags: datatable

How to sorting the datatable according to date format dd-mm-yyyy .. error is here :uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oSort' of undefined datatable error and also the used datatable library

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/date-eu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">


    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$('table.display').DataTable();
            $('#example').dataTable( {
         columnDefs: [
           { type: 'date-eu', targets: 4}
         ]
      } );
    } );
    jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
            if (a == null || a == "") {
                return 0;
            }
            var ukDatea = a.split('/');
            return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
        },

        "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    } );

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I once I had this issue because of referencing scripts in the wrong sequence for loading the datatable. I then changed the order how my scripts were loaded and it solved the issue.